# Android ANPR source code, PATH is not found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, environment-variables, adt

Running on Windows 7, 64bit, Java-ADT

I have download source code from [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-anpr/source/checkout) project, but ndk is not found in path. [image: ndk is not found in path]

I have [download](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) android-ndk-r9c, and set Computer/Properties/Advanced System Settings/Environment Variables (PATH and Path are set to D:\programi\software\android-ndk-r9c\ndk-build), but ndk is not found again [image: ndk is not found again]

And these are my variables in properties 
[image: my variables]

Comment: Did you add NDK directory to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: I have added to PATH and Path env variable D:\programi\software\android-ndk-r9c\ndk-build

Comment: It should be without ndk-build, as far as I know.

Comment: PATH and Path env variable D:\programi\software\android-ndk-r9c as variables in properties, Error: Program "D:\programi\software\android-ndk-r9c" not found in PATH

Comment: Well, I get it now. You are trying to use Eclipse environment variables, which does not work with NDK: I had the similar problem as you months ago and the solution was to add them under Computer/Properties/Advanced System Settings/Environment Variables.

Comment: These are my env var http://s24.postimg.org/fq4s20ngl/image.png

Comment: One last idea that I have. Your build command is missing .cmd at the end. It should be: D:\programi\software\android-ndk-r9c\ndk-build.cmd If it still not working, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Getting this Error: make.***Android NDK:Aborting  .Stop.

Comment: Well, at least your PATH problem is fixed now. Why it gives this error is a matter of another question with details about the project.